# Turing Decryption MIT example

Tags: number-theory

I am learning mathematics for computer science on  OpenCourseWare. I have no clue in  understanding below small mathematical problem.

Encryption: The message m can be any integer in the set $\{0,1,2,\dots,p−1\}$; in par­ticular, the message is no longer required to be a prime. The sender encrypts 
the message $m$ to produce $m^∗$
by computing:
$$m^∗ = \operatorname{remainder}(mk,p).$$

Multiplicative inverses are the key to decryption in Turing’s code. Specfically, 
we can recover the original message by multiplying the encoded message by the 
inverse of the key:
\begin{align*}
m*k^{-1}
&\cong \operatorname{remainder}(mk,p) k^{-1} &&
\text{(the def. (14.8) of $m^*$)} \\
&\cong (mk) k{^-1} \pmod p && \text{(by Cor. 14.5.2)} \\
&\cong m \pmod p.
\end{align*}
This shows that $m*k^{-1}$ is congruent to the original message $m$. Since $m$ was in 
the range $0,1,\dots,p-1$, we can recover it exactly by taking a remainder: 
$m = \operatorname{rem}(m*k^{-1},p)$    --- ???

Can someone please explain the above line (with question marks) I don't understand it.

Comment: Done. Thanks I am posting first time here. Didnt the editor is latex comp.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bravo to you for taking the initiative and learning!

I believe there are some typos in your posting that are throwing you off. I will try to lay this out and hopefully this cleaned up version will make sense.

The message $m$ can be any integer in the set $\{0,1,2,...,p−1\}.$

**Encryption Process:**

We are given a $\text{Plaintext} = P = \text{message} = m$ and want to produce ciphertext (encrypted message), by computing:

$\displaystyle \text{Ciphertext} = C = m^{∗} = \text{remainder}(mk,p)$

**Decryption Process:**

We need to reverse the process to recover the original message by computing:

$\displaystyle \text{Plaintext} = P = (m^{*})k^{-1} \cong (\text{remainder}(mk,p)) k^{-1} \cong (mk) k^{-1}\pmod p \cong m\pmod p.$

We just proved that the message is recoverable using an inverse.

So, now we can say that this shows that $m*k^{-1}$ is congruent to the original message $m$ (we just proved it).

Since m was in the range $\{0,1,...,p-1\}$, we can recover it exactly by:

$$\text{Plaintext} = P = m = \text{remainder}(m^{*}k^{-1},p)$$

This previous line is just doing what we proved, multiplying the ciphertext by the inverse to recover the original message.

Comment: Nice to see you dear friend. :)

Comment: But we still have m(mod p) in the final result. May be I am having trouble understanding congruence. Isn't the encrypted message still modified by (mod p).

Comment: @gopal: m (mod p) is the original message. Recall that you you are typically going to be using a VERY large value for 'p' and that the alphabets we are using are very small in comparison. So, taking that very small alphabet mod p is not an issue. In other words, your message will not be affected mod p prior to encryption or after. Regards

Comment: @Amzoti Thanks for the detailed explanation. Appreciate your time for helping me. Thanks.That explains now.

Comment: @gopal: You are very welcome and keep up the great work! Regards

Comment: Bravo, indeed, Amzoti! $\;+1\;$

Answer (score 2):

The line with the question mark is just a restatement of the explanation above in symbolic form.

We have a message $m$ and encrypted message $m^* = \text{remainder}(mk,p)$. If we are given $m^*$ we can recover $m$ by multiplying by $k^{-1}$ and taking the remainder mod $p$. That is, $\text{remainder}(m^* \cdot k^{-1},p) = \text{remainder}(mkk^{-1},p) = \text{remainder}(m,p) = m$. This gives $m$ exactly (and not something else congruent to $m \mod p$) because $m$ is restricted to be in $0,1,\dots,p-1$.